# Can I make a full page chatbot using Watson Conversation?

Tags: javascript, chatbot, watson-conversation, watson

I want to make a full page chatbot using Watson Conversation (like this: https://www.wmdmark.com/ ), is it possible to do it? If yes, how can I connect the Watson chatbot and my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possible and is a typical usecase. Take a look at the [architecture diagram shown in this overview of Watson Conversation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/index.html#about). The conversation service is invoked by your chatbot. There are samples you can work with for different programming languages, including Javascript. [You could build a Node.js server app that serves webpages with a bot interface to users](https://developer.ibm.com/code/patterns/create-cognitive-banking-chatbot/).